# Remote Synchronisation instead of doing a backup

Tags: backup, 16.10, 17.10, sync

I do not have a lot of experience with Ubuntu. I would like to make a backup of my old computer to put it on my new computer. The problem is that I do not have an external disk. Is it possible to do this same process, but remotely from my old computer directly to my new one? Make a kind of synchronization between the two computers. Namely, I use Ubuntu 16.10 on the old and 17.10 on the new.

Could I do it with `sftp` or `rsync`? Is there exist a better choice? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like rsync would do what you want.

You can also try **unison**, which uses "a version of the rsync protocol" (from the man pages).  **unison-gtk** is available as a graphical version on top of unison which you might want to try.

On the other hand, if you want to do backups at regular intervals (for example, with the scheduling done by cron), you might want to look into **rsnapshot**.

I guess the difference between the last two depends on how you use them, but basically, unison(-gtk) will help you synchronize between two computers.  rsnapshot will take a multiple snapshots at regular intervals using cron (i.e., daily, weekly, etc.); the disk space used is roughly the changes in files between snapshots -- so not a lot.

Perhaps one of the two or a combination of the two is what you're after.  In a way, both are quite similar to rsync, though.  sftp (as far as I know) would just transfer the files over.  Other similar programs might be **scp** or **FileZilla**, but it doesn't sound like it's what you're after.  You might want to use sftp/scp/FileZilla the first time so that the computer doesn't waste time calculating file differences.  Maybe you can play with these options with a small directory before committing on one option.

Do be careful that your time is set correctly.  One problem with synchronization programs is if it thinks that the side you're transferring to is more recent -- then everything from the source side is deleted.  Proceed carefully and triple check before you click "ok".